# Why kiwi matcher raises exception when matching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kiwi

I have implemented example from [Mocking Network Requests With OHHTTPStubs](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/10/mocking-network-requests-with-ohhttpstubs/). Unfotunately I  encountered EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception when matching my result in line:

```
 [[expectFutureValue(origin) shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(3.0)] equal:@"111.222.333.444"];
```

Did anyone encountered this kind of problem?
What could be possible solution?

Here is the full code:

```
#import "Kiwi.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "OHHTTPStubs.h"
#import "OHHTTPStubsResponse.h"

SPEC_BEGIN(NetworkTest)

describe(@"The call to the external service", ^{

    beforeEach(^{
        [OHHTTPStubs addRequestHandler:^OHHTTPStubsResponse*(NSURLRequest *request, BOOL onlyCheck){
            return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithFile:@"test.json" contentType:@"text/json" responseTime:1.0];
         }];
     );

    it(@"should return an IP address", ^{

        __block NSString *origin;
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/ip"]];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            origin = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"origin"];
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)     {
            // no action
        }];

        [operation start];

        [[expectFutureValue(origin) shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(3.0)] equal:@"111.222.333.444"];

    });

});

SPEC_END
```

Comment: How is the `origin` variable declared and assigned?

Comment: I just added full code to the question

Comment: It is NSString*. I have also tried it as (id) type but with the same result.

Comment: Well this hanged up cause origin value was nil at the end which I wasn't expected.

Answer (score 1):

The test does not find the file test.json so it returns  so that is why you get the nil.

Create a file test.json in the same folder as your test file and put the body you need to see the test pass or fail.

To see the test fail

```
{ "origin" : "1.2.3.4"}
```

To see the test pass

```
{ "origin" : "111.222.333.444"}
```

//Note add request handler has been deprecated the following will work

```
[OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return YES; // Stub ALL requests without any condition
} withStubResponse:^OHHTTPStubsResponse*(NSURLRequest *request) {
    // Stub all those requests with our "response.json" stub file
    return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithFile:@"test.json" contentType:@"text/json" responseTime:1.0];
}];
```